# What is this connection error for roberta model?

Tags: python, data-science

I want to run a roberta model, But it has a connection error...
Here is the error: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from scipy.special import softmax
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether or not you have resolved this. But the problem is that your Kaggle notebook is not connected to the internet. You can try opening the setting on the right of your screen, and make sure your internet is toggled on. This may require you to verify your phone number. Good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).